# how to access object of selector instead of the event selector,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was creating custom plugin components using jquery, i have plugin with name inputPinGroup which i can initiate with options, and call methods with the name,

i create custom event "maxedinput" which will trigger when the input is maxed Out the character limit (PIN will max on 6). then in the plugin you can call method like 'disable' and 'loading'
(i will skip the rest pf plugin detail since not tied to the question)

The question is, i want to call the method in the .inputPinGroup of that selected jquery object using some sort of 'THIS' so that it will be more readable,

becase it is inside .on() , when i tried to call $(this).inputPinGroup('disable');
the method won't work,
i tried this.inputPinGroup('disable'); also wont work

how do i access $("#testing-pin-input-group2") using sort of 'this' mechanism?

```
    $("#testing-pin-input-group2").on("maxedinput", (function (event, pinValue, param2) {
      
      setTimeout(function(){
     
        $("#testing-pin-input-group2").inputPinGroup('disable');// work

        $("#testing-pin-input-group2").inputPinGroup('loading');// work

        $(this).inputPinGroup('disable'); // doesnt work, i want to acces the $('#testing-pin-input-group2') so that code is more readable

      },1000);
      })
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(this)[0].inputPinGroup('disable');`? [How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)

Comment: @kmoser i just tried, Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].inputPinGroup is not a function

Comment: _"i will skip the rest pf plugin detail since not tied to the question"_ It seems it is tied to the question. Does `$('#testing-pin-input-group2').inputPinGroup('disable');` work?

Comment: @kmoser yes it does work, i tested. btw i edited the code, i missed the settimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

after hour of searching i cant seem to find way to directly access the 'this' directly, i found kind of workaround from what i expected:

```
  $("#testing-pin-input-group2").on("maxedinput", (function (event, pinValue, param2) {
      var inputGroup = this;

      setTimeout(function(){    
        $(inputGroup).inputPinGroup('disable');
      },2000);
      })
    );
```